# How to display a different name in the "select" component?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a `select` component, it contains an array of columns from a table. How can I make it so that it visually displays a different column name but does not change the original column name in the `COLS` variable? That is, I have the name of the column `NAME` set, and I need to display it as `Full name`.

```
const COLS = ["NAME", "LOGIN", "EMAIL", "ORG","DOLG"];
```

html:

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width">
    <mat-label>Customize Columns</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="displayedColumns" multiple>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let row of allCols" [value]="row">{{ row }}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your constants as an object that contains another key called *displayName* and use that field as the dropdown value :

```
COLS = [ {value : "NAME", displayName: 'My display name'}];
```

and now display them using:

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="displayedColumns" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let row of COLS" [value]="row.value">
       {{ row.displayName }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: Do consider upvoting the answer as well!